# Modal segue no transition

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

How to remove the transition effect from a modal segue when displaying the modal like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier" sender:self];
```

I know I can go into the storyboard and toggle between 4 different animations but I don't want any! How do I remove them?

I know I could say `presentModalViewController animated: NO` but I do not and can not call it this way. I need to use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make a custom segue (without the animation) if you need a segue but don't want the animation.

You should look at Apples ["creating custom segues" example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH16-SW1) in the view controller programming guide, they do a custom modal segue without an animation (just like you wanted).

Answer (score 15):

In the storyboard you can select your segue and in the Attributes Inspector uncheck "Animates". That should do it.

Comment: Best answer! This should be the official answer!

Comment: This works only for Modal style, there is no "Animates" option for push

Answer (score 11):

Here's the full source of a no-animation segue:

*BVNoAnimationSegue.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BVNoAnimationSegue : UIStoryboardSegue
@end
```

*BVNoAnimationSegue.m*

```
#import "BVNoAnimationSegue.h"

@implementation BVNoAnimationSegue

- (void)perform
{
    [[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}

@end
```

To use this, add the files to your project (e.g. as BVNoAnimationSegue.m/.h) then in storyboard, select 'Custom' as your Segue type and type BVNoAnimationSegue in the *Segue Class* box. After you've done this Xcode seems to be clever enough to add 'no animation segue' as an option when you CTRL-drag between UIViewControllers in future.

Answer (score -1):

One more way we can

```
YourViewController *aYourViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aYourViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aYourViewController animated:NO];
```

and add the `@"aYourViewControllerIdentifier"` to view controller in your storyboard.